# Count and Join using access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

Sorry if this seems simple to you guys but I've been struggling for ages:

I have 2 tables `Companies` and `Quotes`. The companies table contains the Rep for the company and I'm trying to get the number of quotes for each company by Rep. The 2 tables are linked by 'Ref' in the Companies table and 'CompanyRef' in the Quotes table.

In a perfect world the list would look something like:

```
Rep,         Company,       (Quote Count)
```

The closest I think I've come is:

```
SELECT Companies.Rep, Companies.Company, COUNT(Quotes) AS [Quote Count] 
FROM Companies    
INNER JOIN Quotes ON Companies.Ref = Quotes.CompanyRef 
GROUP BY Companies.Rep, Companies.Company 
ORDER by Count(Quotes) Desc
```

But I'm just getting

> Too Few Parameters, Expected 1

I should also mention, not every company has a rep allocated.

Any help gratefully appreciated. Steve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the Table name in your Count clause but indicate which Columns you want to count (use * for 'don't care'). If you have the name of the table in the Count function access tries to find a field with that name...

```
SELECT Companies.Rep, Companies.Company, COUNT(*) AS [Quote Count] 
FROM Companies    
INNER JOIN Quotes ON Companies.Ref = Quotes.CompanyRef 
GROUP BY Companies.Rep, Companies.Company 
ORDER by Count(*) Desc
```

Comment: Thanks rene but now I'm getting: Syntax error in query expression 'COUNT(Quotes.*)'

Comment: I must be missing something obvious as I'm back to:

Comment: ...as I'm back to Too Few Parameters. Expected 1

Comment: One small change made to this Rene in the order By (Count(*)) and it worked! Give yourself a pat on the back and thank you.